# How to join my mvc application with a js template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, menu, popupmenu

h, i wanna set my action url in my templates menu but i have no idea how to
this is the _layout.cshtml

```
  <!-- Main Content -->
<div class="lx-g1-f">
    <div class="lx-main-content">
        <div class="lx-g8-f lx-p-10">

            <!-- Main Menu -->
            <div class="lx-main-menu lx-transparent">
                <i class="lnr lnr-menu"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="active" data-title="lx-home" data-url="index-4.html#home"><i class="lnr lnr-home"></i>home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-title="lx-knowme" data-url="index-4.html#knowme"><i class="lnr lnr-user"></i>about me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#skills" data-title="lx-skills" data-url="index-4.html#skills"><i class="lnr lnr-laptop"></i>proffes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-title="lx-resume" data-url="index-4.html#resume"><i class="lnr lnr-graduation-hat"></i>resume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-title="lx-projects" data-url="index-4.html#projects"><i class="lnr lnr-briefcase"></i> projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-title="lx-blog" data-url="index-1.html#blog"><i class="lnr lnr-bullhorn"></i>blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-title="lx-contact" data-url="index-4.html#contact"><i class="lnr lnr-envelope"></i>contact  </a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Main Menu -->
```

this is the action url:

```
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

and this is index.js menu section:

```
  // Main menu event : show correspondant section
$(".lx-main-menu ul li a").on("click", function() {

    var patt = /single-post/;
    if(!patt.test(location.pathname)){  
        // Remove active class from menus
        $(".lx-main-menu ul li a").removeClass("active");
        // Set clicked menu active
        $(this).addClass("active");
        // Hide all blocs
        $(".lx-blocs").removeClass("active");
        // Show the correspondant bloc
        $("."+$(this).attr("data-title")).addClass("active");
        // Update the url
        history.pushState('data', '', $(this).attr("data-url"));

        // If bloc skills load the progress bars
        if($(this).attr("data-title") === "lx-skills"){
            for (var i = 0; i < $(".lx-bar", ".lx-bars-chart").length; i++) {
                $(".lx-bar:eq(" + i + ") .lx-bar-counter").text($(".lx-bar:eq(" + i + ")").attr("data-max") + "%");
                $(".lx-bar:eq(" + i + ") .lx-bar-fill").css("width", $(".lx-bar:eq(" + i + ")").attr("data-max") + "%");
            }
        }
        else{
            for (var i = 0; i < $(".lx-bar", ".lx-bars-chart").length; i++) {
                $(".lx-bar:eq(" + i + ") .lx-bar-counter").text("0%");
                $(".lx-bar:eq(" + i + ") .lx-bar-fill").css("width","0%");
            }       
        }

        // Responsive Menu Hide
        if($(window).width() <= 768){
            $(".lx-main-menu").css("left", "-116px");
            $(".lx-main-menu > i").attr("class", "lnr lnr-menu");       
        }
    }
});
```

please help me to join my action url to my css template
this part is my index.cshtml :

```
<div class="lx-home">
    <div class="lx-home-content">
        <div class="lx-home-overview">
            <h1> </h1>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <em></em>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="lx-clear-fix"></div>
        <div class="lx-home-buttons">

            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this style is single page and the view is like this:

[image: menu in the left side]

[image: menu item 3 opened as a window]

this is the html page

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Where do you try to add those links and what happens when you try?

Answer (score -1):

```
<li><a href=@Url.content("~/controllerName/ActionMethod")"> class="active" data-title="lx-home" ><i class="lnr lnr-home"></i>home</a></li>
```

In layout.cshtml you have give link this. Hope this will help.

Comment: whoever down voted can you please explain the reason.